# How to have Accordin buttons' heights fill the remaining space evenly

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I have developed a layout in which button elements should fill the empty space below them when they are closed . I tried several approaches but no luck.

Here is my code :

```js
var accordion = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++) {
   accordion[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  
   panel = this.nextElementSibling;

            if (panel.style.maxHeight){
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
    for(j = 0; j < accordion.length; j++) {
     if(j != i) {
      accordion[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
      accordion[j].classList.remove('active');
     }
    }
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
   
   this.classList.toggle("active");
        });
    }
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #e0d9d4;
        }

        .container {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .about {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            color : white;
            background-color : black;
        }

        .projects {
            float : right;
            width : 50%;
        }

        .about h2 {
            font-family: Clearface;
            font-size : 80px;
            padding: 30px;
        }

        .about p {
            font-family: Clearface;
            font-size : 30px;
            padding: 30px;
        }

        .accordion {
            background-color: #333648;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: center;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 17px;
            transition: 0.5s;
            
        }

        .active, .accordion:hover {
            background-color: #ccc;
            color: black;
        }

        .panel {
            padding:0 18px;
            background-color: white;
            max-height: 0;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
        }

        .img-responsive {
            display: block;
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            margin: 50px auto;
        }

        .header-img-responsive {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        .post {
            padding: 0 20%;
        }

        .title {
            text-align: center;
            color: #932D26;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="about">
            <h2>
                Hello!
            </h2>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin. Lorem ipsum har varit standard ända sedan 1500-talet, när en okänd boksättare tog att antal bokstäver och blandade dem för att göra ett provexemplar av en bok. Lorem ipsum har inte bara överlevt fem århundraden, utan även övergången till elektronisk typografi utan större förändringar. Det blev allmänt känt på 1960-talet i samband med lanseringen av Letraset-ark med avsnitt av Lorem Ipsum, och senare med mjukvaror som Aldus PageMaker.
            </p>
    </div>

    <div class="projects">
        <button class="accordion">Project 1</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="post">
                <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </p>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">Project 2</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="post">
                <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


                </p>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">Project 3</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="post">
                <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


                </p>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">Project 4</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="post">
                <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


                </p>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">Project 5</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="post">
                <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


                </p>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can I achieve this effect ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: flex` in `.container` class and add `height: 20%` in class `accordion` and it'll work. Check following working code.

```js
var accordion = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++) {
   accordion[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  
   panel = this.nextElementSibling;

            if (panel.style.maxHeight){
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
    for(j = 0; j < accordion.length; j++) {
     if(j != i) {
      accordion[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
      accordion[j].classList.remove('active');
     }
    }
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
   
   this.classList.toggle("active");
        });
    }
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #e0d9d4;
        }

        .container {
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
        }

        .about {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            color : white;
            background-color : black;
        }

        .projects {
            float : right;
            width : 50%;
        }

        .about h2 {
            font-family: Clearface;
            font-size : 80px;
            padding: 30px;
        }

        .about p {
            font-family: Clearface;
            font-size : 30px;
            padding: 30px;
        }

        .accordion {
            background-color: #333648;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20%;
            border: none;
            text-align: center;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 17px;
            transition: 0.5s;
            
        }

        .active, .accordion:hover {
            background-color: #ccc;
            color: black;
        }

        .panel {
            padding:0 18px;
            background-color: white;
            max-height: 0;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
        }

        .img-responsive {
            display: block;
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            margin: 50px auto;
        }

        .header-img-responsive {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        .post {
            padding: 0 20%;
        }

        .title {
            text-align: center;
            color: #932D26;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="about">
            <h2>
                Hello!
            </h2>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum är en utfyllnadstext från tryck- och förlagsindustrin. Lorem ipsum har varit standard ända sedan 1500-talet, när en okänd boksättare tog att antal bokstäver och blandade dem för att göra ett provexemplar av en bok. Lorem ipsum har inte bara överlevt fem århundraden, utan även övergången till elektronisk typografi utan större förändringar. Det blev allmänt känt på 1960-talet i samband med lanseringen av Letraset-ark med avsnitt av Lorem Ipsum, och senare med mjukvaror som Aldus PageMaker.
            </p>
    </div>

    <div class="projects">
        <button class="accordion">Project 1</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="post">
                <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </p>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">Project 2</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="post">
                <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


                </p>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">Project 3</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="post">
                <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


                </p>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">Project 4</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="post">
                <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


                </p>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="accordion">Project 5</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="post">
                <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


                </p>
                <div>
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What to do if I wanted them to keep their height fixed whether they are open or not ?